# Meaning of LOGFONT's lfClipPrecision enum values

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts, gdi, wmf

[`LOGFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms915433(v=msdn.10)) has an `lfClipPrecision` field:

> The clipping precision defines how to clip characters that are partially outside the clipping region.

Possible values of the enum are described here: [ClipPrecision Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wmf/c85e4c50-f581-4d22-826c-854e7b50e75d)

The descriptions are a bit vague, so for `CLIP_STROKE_PRECIS` we get:

> This value MAY be returned when enumerating rasterized, TrueType and vector fonts.

My question is, what does it mean to have clip precision equal to `CLIP_STROKE_PRECIS`? Do I let partial character overflows slip past the clipping region's boundary and not be clipped? Or do I clip a stroke if it does not entirely fit within the clipping region, subsequently leaving a partial character?

Likewise, for `CLIP_DFA_DISABLE`:

> This value specifies that font association SHOULD be turned off.

To clip or not to clip, that is the question...

Comment: There are few examples of using `CLIP_STROKE_PRECIS` parameter. I didn't find the difference, can you describe it in more detail? It would be better if you could add relevant screenshots.

Comment: The only description of `CLIP_STROKE_PRECIS` I could find is in the link. Not sure what screenshots you have in mind. The context of the problem is building an EMF viewer.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example in the question?

Comment: Unfortunately the  actual code example would not be that minimal, was just hoping that someone is familiar with Windows API that could explain the usage of the enum values.

Comment: [LOGFONTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfonta) provided more information.  For compatibility, this value is always returned when enumerating fonts.  When I use `EnumFontFamiliesEx` to enumerate fonts, the `lfClipPrecision` parameter will always return the `CLIP_STROKE_PRECIS` value. This is consistent with the behavior stated in the documentation. For clipping precision, I did some tests, not sure where it was used. Maybe you can provide some code for my reference.